Split and Replace First Word of A String in VBA
I have this date data for example: Monday, September 9, 2024. I wish to replace the day into my language, for ex: monday to senin, tuesday to selasa, and so on. I've tried creating the code, but it doesn't give any results.
Dim iz As Integer
    Dim lsw As Long
    
    lsw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For iz = 2 To lsw
    Range("G" & iz) = Replace(LCase(Range("G" & iz)), "Monday", "Senin")
    Range("G" & iz) = Replace(LCase(Range("G" & iz)), "Tuesday", "Selasa")
    Range("G" & iz) = Replace(LCase(Range("G" & iz)), "Wednesday", "Rabu")
    Range("G" & iz) = Replace(LCase(Range("G" & iz)), "Thursday", "Kamis")
    Range("G" & iz) = Replace(LCase(Range("G" & iz)), "Friday", "Jumat")
    Range("G" & iz) = Replace(LCase(Range("G" & iz)), "Saturday", "Sabtu")
    Range("G" & iz) = Replace(LCase(Range("G" & iz)), "Sunday", "Minggu")


Also, I wish to change the date into this format
Monday, September 9, 2024 to Senin, 9 September 2024
Could anyone give me a feedback if this is possible.

Are the dates actual dates - if you look in the formula bar does it say 09/09/2024 or Monday, September 9, 2024?

Place the date value as number in the cell, and format the cell (NumberFormatLocale or NumberFormat) to your locale.

International Date Format

To show the dates in Indonesian format, prefix the desired date format with either [$-id-ID] or [$-421] (US is [$-en-US] or [$-409]).


Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("G2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))

rg.NumberFormat = "[$-id-ID]dddd, d mmmm yyyy" ' or "[$-421]dddd, d mmmm yyyy"

